# how to serve calls from api and static resource(coming from s3) under the same domain EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I am working in a spring boot application which later is wrapped up by docker and deployed using Amazon EKS.
I also have a static page on amazon s3.

I am fully aware that my spring boot application can serve static content but I would like the client and server to be fully detached.

I would have liked to use AWS infra to service calls, once a call is /index.html go and get the static data, otherwise, it's an API call from my service which requires RBAC, etc ...

in other applications, I would have just put LB such as HA-PROXY and decide all the calls with pattern x goes to the UI the other goes to the server.

how can I do this using AWS tools? 
what is the advised way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html
the problem is we are routing to S3 bucket while it's more applicable to do it to folder ...